# Jpa ManytoMany issue with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have a postgres database and I am trying to make a simple REST service with Spring Boot. I have a problem with jpa ManytoMany relationship.

Person Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person", schema = "persons")
public class Person implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String name;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String email;

@Column
private Integer age;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "country_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Country countryOfBirth;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name="persons_countries_residence",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="person_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
private List<Country> countriesOfResidence;

// getters and setters and to String method overriden
}
```

Country Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "country", schema = "persons")
public class Country implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "country_name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "country_code")
private String code;

 // getters and setters and to String method overriden
}
```

The postgres schema is the following:

Person Table:

```
CREATE TABLE persons.person
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  name character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  email character varying(40) NOT NULL,
  age integer,
  country_id serial NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT id PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT country_id FOREIGN KEY (id)
  REFERENCES persons.country (id) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
 )
```

Country table:

```
CREATE TABLE persons.country
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  country_name character varying(45) NOT NULL,
  country_code character varying(10) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT country_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Join table:

```
CREATE TABLE persons.persons_countries_residence
(
  person_id integer NOT NULL,
  country_id integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT person_country_id PRIMARY KEY (person_id, country_id),
  CONSTRAINT persons_countries_residence_country_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (country_id)
  REFERENCES persons.country (id) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT persons_countries_residence_person_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (person_id)
  REFERENCES persons.person (id) MATCH SIMPLE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
 )
```

When i make an HTTP method call, I don't get the Countries of residence.

Service code:

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces =   {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
 public List<Person> getAllPersons() {
     retutn jpaPersonRepository.findAll();
 }
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is this:

```
  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(
        name="persons_countries_residence", schema = "persons",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="person_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
private List<Country> countriesOfResidence;
```

The schema had to be specified at the `@JoinTable` annotation as well.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, you need to specify a schema name in the join table name:

```
@JoinTable(
        name="persons_countries_residence", schema="persons",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="person_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
```

Comment: If i do that i get exception: `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "persons_persons_countries_residence" does not exist`

Answer (score 1):

Update your Country class code like :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "country", schema = "persons")
public class Country implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "country_name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "country_code")
private String code;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "countriesOfResidence")
private List<Person> persons;

 // getters and setters and to String method overriden
}
```

> Although a ManyToMany relationship is always bi-directional on the
>   database, the object model can choose if it will be mapped in both
>   directions, and in which direction it will be mapped in. If you choose
>   to map the relationship in both directions, then one direction must be
>   defined as the owner and the other must use the mappedBy attribute to
>   define its mapping. This also avoids having to duplicate the JoinTable
>   information in both places.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that the country list is null? `@ManyToMany` associations are lazily loaded by default, you need to enable eager-fetching for it to work straight away.

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
```

Comment: Yes, the country list is null. All others fields have values though. Setting `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` did not solve that. (At the persons.persons_countries_residence table I have set two existing id's for person and country which exist).